# Is it possible to secure a load balanced endpoint in Azure?

Tags: web-services, security, azure, load-balancing, endpoint

Is there any way I can have a load balanced endpoint that does not get exposed publicly in Azure?

My scenario is I have an endpoint running on multiple VM's. I can create a load balanced endpoint, but this creates a publicly available endpoint.

I only want my load balanced endpoint to be available for my web applications running in Azure (Web Workers and Azure Websites).

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Brent pointed out, you can set up ACL's on Virtual Machine endpoints. One thing you mentioned in your question was the ability to restrict inbound traffic to only your web/worker role instances and Web Sites traffic.

You can certainly restrict traffic to web/worker instances, as each cloud service gets an IP address, so you just need to allow that particular IP address. Likewise, you can use ACLS to restrict traffic to other Virtual Machine deployments (especially in the case where you're not using a Virtual Network). Web Sites, on the other hand, don't offer a dedicated outbound IP address, so you won't be able to use ACLs to manage Web Sites traffic to your Virtual Machines.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Windows Azure IaaS supports ACL's on endpoints. Using this feature, you can restrict who connects to your load balanced endpoints. For more information see: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-acl/

Comment: It appears that this solution is helpful in some scenarios, but does not solve the issue of ensuring a load balanced endpoint is only accessible by my Azure Website(s)?